# Some function to sleep in Vala

Tags: glib, vala

In Python there is a function called `Time.Sleep ()` to pause the execution of a period of time, some alternative in Vala.

What I try to do is execute a While (True) but the content is executed in a certain period of time, for example 5 seconds.

Comment: This is a bit too trivial for a useful stackoverflow question, ... Just use your favorite web search engine or lookup GLib.Thread.usleep on valadoc.org

Comment: Also depending on your context, you may want to look at https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Timeout.add.html

Comment: The documentation on the main event loop might be of interest as well: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.description

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use this function.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe have a look at the async example here:

```
// Build with: valac --pkg=gio-2.0 example.vala

public async void nap (uint interval, int priority = GLib.Priority.DEFAULT) {
  GLib.Timeout.add (interval, () => {
      nap.callback ();
      return false;
    }, priority);
  yield;
}

private async void do_stuff () {
  yield nap (1000);
}

private static int main (string[] args) {
  GLib.MainLoop loop = new GLib.MainLoop ();
  do_stuff.begin ((obj, async_res) => {
      loop.quit ();
    });
  loop.run ();

  return 0;
}
```

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/AsyncSamples